# Android studio XML autocomplete not working properly after converting java code into Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, build.gradle

**After updating my project from java to Kotlin unable to get suggestion in** `XML` file.

[Code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6C3E.png)

[Code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLTgs.png)

[Code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAgy2.png)

[Code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1JMN.png)

Comment: Have you tried to invalidate caches of Android Studio and restart it?

Comment: @RomanPopov I try out couple of  solutions like invalidate the caches , delete the .idea and .gradle folder , clean and build etc . but nothing work

Comment: Issue with the targetSDK 33            https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/235792434

Comment: What is your targeted SDK? is databinding enabled?

Answer (score 7):

the issue with targetSDK 33 i change it to targetSDK32 and everything work fine

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I have this issue too.
Your advice work, thank you, but I updated some libs, and then project not builds.